Building a PyPi package using setuptools & pyproject.toml with a custom directory tree
I have a custom directory structure which is not the traditional "src" or "flat" layouts setuptools expects.
This is a sample of the directory tree:
my_git_repo/
├── Dataset/
│ ├── __init__.py
│ ├── data/
│ │ └── some_csv_file.csv
│ ├── some_ds1_script.py
│ └── some_ds2_script.py
└── Model/
├── __init__.py
├── utils/
│ ├── __init__.py
│ ├── some_utils1_script.py
│ └── some_utils2_script.py
└── some_model/
├── __init__.py
├── some_model_script.py
└── trained_models/
├── __init__.py
└── model_weights.pkl

Lets say that my package name inside the pyproject.toml is "my_ai_package" and the current packages configuration is:
[tools.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["*"]
namespaces = false

After building the package, what I currently get is inside my site-packages directory I have the Dataset & Model directories
What I want is a main directory called "my_ai_package" and inside it the Dataset & Model directories, I want to be able to do "from my_ai_package import Dataset.some_ds1_script"
I can't re-structure my directory tree to match src/flat layouts, I need some custom configuration in pyptoject.toml
Thanks!

What is the constraint that prevents you from restructuring the folder? If you really can't restructure it then maybe a build tool (like make or fabric) may be useful. You could use it to shuffle things around into a "build" folder and then build it. Not ideal but could be a "quick fix".

@exhuma The main constraint is testing everything after the restructuring phase, what is fabric btw? I only found a "library designed to execute shell commands remotely over SSH"

fabric is a "task-runner". Actually, for your case invoke, which fabric is based on, is sufficient. There are other task-runner (like make for example). "invoke" tasks are written in Python so they will be familiar to you. And it's very powerful due to the extensive standard-library. However, using a task-runner is only a band-aid and will add complexity. Unfortunately, the best (and most maintainable) solution is restructuring. But I understand your constraint, so a task-runner may be a good compromise.

I ended up re-structuring my project in a "src" layout where "src" is replaced by my package name
